# FIREBASE 4 Value of type 'StorageReference' has no member 'put'

Tags: swift, firebase

I have a problem with my first app I've ever wrote. I watched a tutorial on YouTube on how to let users signup with Firebase and choose a profile picture. In the video everything went as it should, but in my project it gives me following bug:

> Value of type 'StorageReference' has no member 'put'

I already saw a post on this topic, but I coldnt work with this answer given there ([Value of type 'StorageReference' has no member 'put'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44101727/value-of-type-storagereference-has-no-member-put)).

Here is my complete code:

```
let uploadTask = imageRef.put(data!, metadata: nil, completition: { (metadata, error) in

                    if err != nil{
                        print(err!.localizedDescription)
                    }

                    imageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, er) in
                        if er != nil{
                            print(er!.localizedDescription)
                        }

                        if let url = url {

                            let userInfo: [String: Any] = ["uid" : user.uid,
                                                           "full name" : self.nameField.text!,
                                                           "urlToImage" : url.absoluteString]

                            self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(userInfo)


                            let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController
                            (withIdentifier: "userVC")

                            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }

                    })

                })
```

The error comes in the first line.

Comment: According to the duplicate question your linked: `put(data!...)` => `putData(data!...)` Also, if you write just `put`, does the autocompletion help you?

Comment: Unfortunately not :-( I tried pretty much every solution I found but nothing helped me, so I needed to ask again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files) and the question you linked, the latest version of Firebase uses `putData`, not `put`.

```
let uploadTask = imageRef.putData(data!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in

  // your code here

})
```

Comment: It is still giving me the same error as before, also there are a few new Errors saying " 'err' is unavailable: Variadic function is unavailable " :-(

Comment: Yeah, you called it `error` in the function, but then referred to it as `err` in the body of the function

Comment: Oh you are right - but I still got the same error I had in the beginning.

Comment: Thank you so much - I got it work by just rewriting everything in thisfile :-)